# Totally remove a vagrant box(?) from my host

Tags: vagrant

After `vagrant halt` and  `vagrant destroy` and after a `cd && cd .vagrant/boxes && rm -rf ...` I've been continuing to see a box.

I've also pruned vagrant cache with command `vagrant global-status --prune`.

Here the output of `vagrant status`:

```
Current machine states:

my-vagrant-api                    not created (virtualbox)
```

What I need to do to totally remove Vagrant box from an Host?

Comment: Where do you see the machine? Are you using VirtualBox provider? Is it in the VirtualBox interface? Or else...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nothing you have to do. It is already deleted.**

It is only showing vagrant machine configuration that you defined in `Vagrantfile`. See the output:

```
my-vagrant-api                    not created (virtualbox)
```

It is saying vagrant machine with name `my-vagrant-api` is defined in `Vagrantfile` but `not created`.

If it is created then it will look like:

```
 vagrant status
Current machine states:

server1                   poweroff (virtualbox)
server2                   poweroff (virtualbox)
server3                   running (virtualbox)

This environment represents multiple VMs. The VMs are all listed
above with their current state. For more information about a specific
VM, run `vagrant status NAME`.
```

If you don't want this configuration then you can simply delete that `Vagrantfile`